# Roll Up/Wind Up/Coil Up

Tags: differences, expression-choice

Are the three equivalents?

can you say:

**Roll** the cord **up**

**Wind** the cord **up**

**Coil** the cord **up**

Are the three equivalents?

Answer (score 2):

The results are similar, but they imply different methods of achieving the goal.

*Roll up* implies that there is a spool around which the cord is rolled.

*Wind up* implies that there is a spool, and furthermore, that the spool has a cranking mechanism — some kind of handle.

*Coil up* is the most basic form, and only states that the cord ends up in some kind of circular or helical configuration.

Comment: But they can't always be used interchangeably. Imagine if somebody said "coil up an toy car" instead of "wind up a toy car." The words are similar and can be used interchangeably often, but not always. It's a matter of context.

Comment: @Arradras Good point, that the meanings are context sensitive, and the answer applies only to cords. _Coiling_ a spring would refer to the manufacturing process; _winding_ a spring is something a user would do; _rolling_ a spring doesn't make much sense (unless you're rolling the whole spring down a ramp or something).